# How to store json file locally for quick access

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

Is there any way I can download json file from webserver and store it in a local folder for easy access for those with poor internet connection, so data will be downloaded once and user won't have to suffer every time.

I found similar questions on [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852949/how-to-write-json-file-in-ios) and [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632500/how-would-i-go-about-saving-a-json-file-from-a-webservice-to-a-local-json-file?rq=1), but they were asked for objective-C, but I was looking something for Swift. Thanks

Comment: there are better ways for persistent data. you can use Coredata or realm for data persistent.

Comment: I need to find a quick resolution to store data locally, as a long term solution I will later look into CoreData but not now, thanks for suggestions though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly do this. After you've read the remote `JSON`, it will be a `Data` object.<sup>1</sup>

Build a `URL` to a path in your app's `caches` directory and then use the `Data` method `write(to:options:)` to write that data into your file.

On read, check to see if the file exists in the `caches` directory before triggering a network read. Note that you need to be sure that the filenames you use are consistent and unique. (The same filename must always fetch the same unique data.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that Mohammad has a good point. There are better ways of persisting your data than saving the raw JSON. Core Data is a pretty complex framework with a steep learning curve, but there are other options as well. You might look at conforming to the Codable protocol, which would let you serialize/deserialize your data objects in a variety of formats including JSON, property lists, and (shudder) XML.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a .json file and store it in documents folder. First see how to create .json file, and then see how to store a file in documents folder.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46903568/3739902)

Comment: It’s the same link given in the question, it’s objective-c

Comment: The one answer I linked most definitely isn't objective c.

Comment: For something like this that can be recovered from the remote server easily, the caches folder is a better choice than the Documents folder. Apple wants you to only use the Documents folder for user content that can't be easily re-aquired.